# .NET How to open CSV with Excel Interop without text converted to formulas

Tags: vb.net, excel, csv, excel-interop

I'm currently presented with the following issue:

I need to open a CSV file with the Excel Interop Classes (15.0). This is done using the following code:

```
  Dim app As New Excel.Application
  Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook = app.Workbooks.Open(sFileNameCSV, Format:=4, Local:=True)
```

Unfortunately this converts some of the data into formulas (e.g. text starting with a hyphen [- this is an example] or phone numbers in international format [+41-555-123-45-67]) resulting in either a #NAME? error or a calculated result in case of the phone number.

After some searching in the web and on SO I tried the following things with no luck:

- Saving the CSV File as a .txt file
- Using the OpenText() Method instead of the Open() method
- Combination of the two above

Is there any solution to this issue without having to change the CSV file data itself and still using the Interop classes, like disabling formulas altogether? Or am I just missing a param in the Open() / OpenText() functions?